# How can I make Eclipse use the indentation style a file already uses?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, indentation, spaces

I am working on a very large, very old codebase in which some files use tabs for indentation and some use spaces.

When making a change, I want eclipse to follow the indentation style of the current file. Is there a setting/plugin to add this functionality?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Can't you just harmonize the codebase to use either only spaces or tabs?

Comment: Although that would be the best way forward, it is not something I can do without getting in the way of active development.

Comment: I understand the benefit of having the same indentation style for the entire codebase, but what is the benefit of having the same indentation style per file instead of per line? IMHO such clean-up work should be part of the active development. As long as this clean-up work is not done, I would recommend choosing an indentation style and applying it to all new and edited lines to avoid them being changed again when doing the clean-up work.